# docker does not run on coral dev board mini

Tags: google-coral

I'm trying to run docker on a dev board mini.

It fails as there are no available [storage drivers](https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/) for docker to use.

The actual error is:

```
ERRO[2021-01-07T22:22:55.681739968Z] [graphdriver] prior storage driver devicemapper failed: devicemapper: Error running deviceCreate (CreatePool) dm_task_run failed
```

Is it possible to compile the overlay kernel module for the dev board mini? Any instructions would be appreciated. Or other suggestion to get docker running.
Coral dev board (not mini) had the overlay kernel module and could run docker out of the box.

Answer (score 3):

I got it to work by rebuilding the kernel [instructions](https://coral.googlesource.com/docs/+/refs/heads/master/GettingStarted.md)

1. checkout the source
2. add the options (listed at the end of the post) to the kernel config in `packages/linux-mtk/debian/defconfig`
3. build with `m docker-linux-mtk`
4. install with `mdt install out/target/product/mt8167s_excelsior/packages/bsp/linux-image-4.19.125-mtk_4-2_arm64.deb`

kernel options to use:

```
CONFIG_OVERLAY_FS=y

CONFIG_IKCONFIG=y
CONFIG_IKCONFIG_PROC=y
CONFIG_CPUSETS=y
CONFIG_FAIR_GROUP_SCHED=y
CONFIG_MEMCG=y
CONFIG_CGROUP_DEVICE=y
CONFIG_CGROUP_FREEZER=y
CONFIG_BLK_CGROUP=y
CONFIG_CGROUP_PIDS=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_ADVANCED=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_ADDRTYPE=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_CONNTRACK=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_CGROUP=y

CONFIG_NETFILTER_XTABLES=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MARK=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_SET=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_TARGET_AUDIT=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_TARGET_CHECKSUM=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_TARGET_CONNMARK=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_TARGET_CONNSECMARK=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_TARGET_CT=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_TARGET_DSCP=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_TARGET_HL=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_TARGET_HMARK=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_TARGET_LED=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_TARGET_LOG=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_NAT=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_TARGET_NETMAP=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_TARGET_RATEEST=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_TARGET_REDIRECT=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_TARGET_MASQUERADE=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_TARGET_TEE=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_TARGET_TPROXY=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_TARGET_TRACE=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_TARGET_SECMARK=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_TARGET_TCPOPTSTRIP=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_BPF=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_CLUSTER=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_COMMENT=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_CONNLABEL=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_CONNLIMIT=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_CONNMARK=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_CPU=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_DCCP=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_DEVGROUP=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_DSCP=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_ECN=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_ESP=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_HASHLIMIT=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_HELPER=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_HL=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_IPCOMP=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_IPVS=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_L2TP=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_NFACCT=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_OSF=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_OWNER=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_PKTTYPE=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_RATEEST=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_SCTP=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_SOCKET=y

CONFIG_VETH=y
```

Comment: One other one that I needed to add:

`CONFIG_DM_THIN_PROVISIONING=y`

Also, you might want to mention rebooting after installing the new kernel.